# Error in Java Insertion Sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

I've attempted to code an Insertion Sort in java via pseudo code from a book. The output for this code should be numbers in ascending order but for some reason I get 10,4,5,6,7,8,9. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
public class InsertionSort {

    public int Array[] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InsertionSort obj1 = new InsertionSort();
    }

    public InsertionSort() {
        InsertionSortMethod();
        PrintArray();
    }

    public void InsertionSortMethod() {
        for(int j = 2; j < Array.length; j++) {
            int key = Array[j];
            int i = j - 1;
            while(i > 0 && Array[i] > key) {
                Array[i + 1] = Array[i];
                i = i - 1;
            }
            Array[i + 1] = key;
        }   
    }

    public void PrintArray() {
        for(int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the for loop from j=1 like this :

```
for(int j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
```

and modify while loop condition like this:

```
while(i >= 0 && array[i] > key) {
```

Correct working code :

```
public class InsertionSort {

public int array[] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    InsertionSort obj = new InsertionSort();
    obj.insertionSortMethod();
    obj.printArray();
}


public void insertionSortMethod() {
    for(int j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        int key = array[j];
        int i = j - 1;
        while(i >= 0 && array[i] > key) {
            array[i + 1] = array[i];
            i = i - 1;
    }
        array[i + 1] = key;

    }   
}

public void printArray() {
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the third line of your code i.e.,

```
InsertionSort obj1 = new InsertionSort();
```

You are making an object of InsertionSort class but in your code, it is defined as a function I think it is a constructor you must mention the class for more convenience of the reader.

Apart from that, you are starting your loop with 2  `for(int j = 2; j < Array.length; j++)`
why so? your one element got missed so start j with 1 
:)

Comment: Thanks for the advice Asheesh! Just to clarify, the algorithm starts by comparing j = 2 and i = j - 1.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the answers. I have also found by tracing the algorithm that flipping the second 'greater than' sign to a 'less than' sign on the 5th line of the algorithm does the trick for working in descending order. This may possibly be a typo in the book i'm reading. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

try this method

```
 public int[] insertionSort(int[] list) {
            int i, j, key, temp;
            for (i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
                key = list[i];
                j = i - 1;
                while (j >= 0 && key < list[j]) {
                    temp = list[j];
                    list[j] = list[j + 1];
                    list[j + 1] = temp;
                    j--;
                }

            }
            return list;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.borntoinnovation.datastructure;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortingInsertion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[] { 4, 3, 2, 20, 12, 1, 5, 6 };

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (array[i] < array[j]) {
                    int temp = array[i];
                    for (int k = i; k > j; k--) {
                        array[k] = array[k - 1];
                    }
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        }

    }// end of main()
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.